# SQL script to rebuild indexes - Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Group'

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a fairly basic SQL script to rebuild all the table indexes under various schema within a database. The script seems to work on the 183 indexes I have, but returns the error message

```
(183 row(s) affected)
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Group'
```

Can anyone explain why and provide a solution?

```
USE RedGateMonitor;
GO
declare @db varchar(150)

declare @tmp TABLE(recnum int IDENTITY (1,1), tableschema varchar(150), tablename varchar(150))
insert @tmp (tableschema, tablename)
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.tables where TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
ORDER By TABLE_SCHEMA
declare @X int, @table varchar(150), @cmd varchar(500), @schema varchar(150)
set @X = 1


While @X <= (select count(*) from @tmp) BEGIN
set @db = 'RedGateMonitor'
set @table = (select tablename from @tmp where recnum = @X)
set @schema = (select tableschema from @tmp where recnum = @X)

set @cmd = 'ALTER INDEX ALL ON ' + @db + '.' + @schema + '.' + @table +  ' REBUILD'
EXECUTE(@cmd)

set @X = @X + 1

END
```

Comment: instead use Ola Hallegren's tried and tested script: http://ola.hallengren.com/

Comment: you error is probably because you are not quoting schema and table names with '[]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with both of Mitch's comments:

(1) you should be using an existing solution for this instead of reinventing the wheel.

(2) if you aren't going to follow basic rules for identifiers (e.g. not naming schemas or tables with reserved words), you need to properly escape them. A quick fix would be:

```
set @cmd = 'ALTER INDEX ALL ON ' + quotename(@db) 
  + '.' + quotename(@schema) 
  + '.' + Quotename(@table) +  ' REBUILD;';
```

A slightly better fix would be the following, with no need for #temp tables or looping:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += N'ALTER INDEX ALL ON ' + QUOTENAME(@db) 
  + '.' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME([schema_id])
  + '.' + QUOTENAME(name) + ' REBUILD;';

EXEC sp_executesql;
```

But I don't think you need to rebuild all of the indexes on all of the tables in the Red Gate database. Scripts like Ola's will help you be more efficient about which indexes to rebuild, which to reorganize, and which to leave alone.

Comment: Thank you both very much. I am aware of Ola's script and that I do not need to rebuild all indexes, I was just stumped as to why this was generating an error. Thanks again